# Armature and rigging for this sphere robot with tentacles?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

Robot in question:

[image]

I'd like to move about the robot like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKfdy050JMQ

1:50 to 2:00

How is the armature and rigging applied? Also, how are the tentacles joined to both the main body and its "feet"?

Comment: I guess you just parent the empties at the ends of the tentacles to the body and the feet respectively (CTRL P - Set Parent to Object (keep transform)) and work from there.

Comment: @John Eason, thanks

Comment: There's a 2-part YT tutorial on creating and rigging robotic arms [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2HCxy4Kh4E) which you could easily modify to create the same effect.

Comment: @John Eason thanks for this recommendation